# Using Several Different Functions in C

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a program that asks the user to enter two numbers M and N. The program then creates a two dimensional array array[M][N].

Four other functions need to be used which include:

- PrintArray(): prints elements in an M x N matrix
- PopulateRandom(): Assigns random values to all elements from 1 to M * N
- LinearSearch(): looks to see if any values are repeated
- LeftShift(): Shifts all elements of the array one to the left, First element becomes last element.

The problem with my code is that when I run it, and enter two values, the program keeps printing the default case "Enter 1 or 0" an infinite times. Can someone help me out?

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool LinearSearch(int[][N], int);
void PopulateRandom(int[][N]);
void PrintArray2D(int[][N]);
void LeftShift(int[][N]);

// Prints elements of array in a M x N table
void PrintArray2D(int array[][N]) {
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      printf("%d", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

// Assigns elements of the array "array" random values
void PopulateRandom(int array[][N]) {
  int i, j, x;

  for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      bool found = 1;
      while (found == 1) {
        x = rand() % M * N - 1;
        found = LinearSearch(array, x);
      }
      array[i][j] = x;
    }
  }
}

// functino performs a linear search to see if there are any repeated values
// in the array.
bool LinearSearch(int array[][N], int num) {
  bool p_flag = 0;
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (array[i][j] == num) {
        p_flag = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return p_flag;
}

void LeftShift(int array[][N]) {
  int i;
  int j;

  for (i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
      if (j == N - 1) {
        if (i == M - 1) {
          array[i][j] = array[0][0];
        } else {
          array[i][j] = array[i + 1][0];
        }
      } else {
        array[i][j] = array[i][j + 1];
      }
    }
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int option;

  printf("If you would like to search ann array, enter 1 \n: ");
  printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");
  scanf("%d", &option);

  while (option != 0) {
    switch (option) {
      case 1: {
        printf("Enter two numbers M and N: ");
        scanf("%d %d", &M, &N);
        int array[M][N];
        PopulateRandom(array);
        PrintArray2D(array);
        LeftShift(array);
        PrintArray2D(array);
        break;
      }
      case 0:
        break;
      default:
        printf("Enter 1 or 0");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `while(option != 0)` is an infinite loop unless option `0` was entered, since you never modify `option` inside the loop.  Perhaps you should move `scanf("%d",&option);` inside the loop, and also check the return value of scanf.

Comment: @M.M or when any invalid option was chosen. And when 1 is chosen, it also loops forever.

Comment: learn to step through your code with a debugger - things like this become obvious

Comment: `scanf("%d %d", &M, &N);` - there are no variables `M` or `N` in this code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int main(void) {
   int option = 1;
   while (option != 0) {
      printf("If you would like to search ann array, enter 1 \n: ");
      printf("If you would like to exit, enter 0 \n: ");
      scanf("%d", &option); // << into the loop
      switch (option) {
```

Answer (score 1):

There happens to be an infinite loop at `while (option != 0)`.
You need to modify your `while` loop.

```
int option = 1; /* initialisation prevents UB, if you're moving the `scanf` into the loop */
while(option != 0)
{
    scanf("%d", &option);
}
```

Noting that `scanf` returns a value corresponding to success/failure, this could also be placed into the conditional expression of the loop, which would avoid the need for an unnecessary (but nonetheless useful) initialisation:

```
int option;
while (scanf("%d", &option) == 1 && option != 0) {
    switch (option) { ... }
}
```

If you expect the input to be processed line-by-line, think about what might happen if the user enters something invalid, such as "invalid" when they're entering an option.

In the first case, the return value corresponding to input failure is discarded, the input stream will remain unchanged (meaning "invalid" is left for future reads) and thus an undesirable infinite loop will occur.

In the second case, the return value corresponding to input failure isn't discarded; in fact, it'll cause the loop to terminate. You might wish to print an error message and re-prompt the user for a valid selection, so here's a third case:

```
int option;
for (int v = scanf("%d", &option); v != EOF && option != 0; v = scanf("%d", &option)) {
    if (!v) {
        puts("ERROR! Invalid selection; try again...");
        scanf("%*[^\n]"); /* This discards the junk... */
        getchar();        /* This discards the newline following the junk,
                           * which is unnecessary in your situation       */
        continue;
    }
    switch (option) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yea i fixed that error, but when I run it now, after I enter values for M and N, it doesn't terminate, but it literally does nothing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! While moving in the right direction, this answer is a little incomplete. Do you mind if I build upon it?

Comment: @Seb yeah, sure. i am a noob in coding actually :P

Comment: @ShoaibAhmed what exactly are you getting?